# Accessing individual components in a JSON websocket feed using python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, websocket

I am using polygon.io to provide data feed for stock data and I am stuck at the beginning.

The responses from the websocket feed is json, the goal is to take responses and write them to a file then have the data imported into a pandas dataframe for analysis.

Where I am having trouble is i am unable to parse the json.  on the on_message funtion, i wanted to see if the "ev" is either "status" or "AM" if its status i wanted to output the message, when the output is "AM" i want to map the data fields to the pandas data frame and save the data in a csv file for historical data.

```
import config, settings
import websocket, json, datetime,pprint

#, talib, numpy, pandas as pd


def on_open(ws):
    print("opened")
    auth_data = {
        "action": "auth",
        "params":config.API_KEY}


    ws.send(json.dumps(auth_data))

    listen_message =  {"action":"subscribe",
                "params": settings.QUOTES }

    ws.send(json.dumps(listen_message))

def on_message(ws, message):
    json_message = json.loads(message)
    pprint.pprint(json_message)
    
#lines of code that im struggling with
    if json_message['ev']=="status":
        print(message['message']) 


def on_close(ws):
    print("closed connection")

socket = "wss://socket.polygon.io/stocks"

ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(socket, on_open=on_open, on_message=on_message, on_close=on_close)
ws.run_forever()
```

the current output is below:

```
opened
[{'ev': 'status', 'message': 'Connected Successfully', 'status': 'connected'}]
[{'ev': 'status', 'message': 'authenticated', 'status': 'auth_success'}]
[{'ev': 'status', 'message': 'subscribed to: AM.F', 'status': 'success'}]
[{'ev': 'status', 'message': 'subscribed to: AM.BAC', 'status': 'success'}]
[{'ev': 'status', 'message': 'subscribed to: AM.AAL', 'status': 'success'}]
[{'ev': 'status', 'message': 'subscribed to: AM.GE', 'status': 'success'}]
```

am i missing something? how am i supposed to capture the data here